# Begin loop with end of previous loop (Excel vba - For Loop)

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I have following code

```
Sub Example()

    Dim l1 As Integer

    Dim l2 As Integer

    Dim l3 As Integer

    For l3 = 1 To 2

        For l1 = 1 To 2

            For l2 = 8 To 9

                MsgBox l1 & "-" & l2

            Next l2

        Next l1

    Next l3

End sub
```

Output: 1-8,1-9,2-8,2-9,1-8,1-9,2-8,2-9.

Need output: 1-8,1-9,2-8,2-9,1-8,1-9,2-8,2-9,10-18,10-19,11-18,11-19,10-18,10-19,11-18,11-19.

In l3 second loop take the max value increment with 1 of previous loop dynamicaly.

End Sub

Comment: I don't get the logic of why it should go to 10-18 second time round? I can see that 10 is one more than 9 (the last value of the L2 loop when L3=1) but not why L2 should start at 18.

Answer (score 0):

Just repeat your loop changing values:

```
Sub Example()

Dim l1 As Integer

Dim l2 As Integer

Dim l3 As Integer

For l3 = 1 To 2

    For l1 = 1 To 2

        For l2 = 8 To 9

            Debug.Print l1 & "-" & l2

        Next l2

    Next l1

Next l3

For l3 = 10 To 11

    For l1 = 10 To 11

        For l2 = 18 To 19

            Debug.Print l1 & "-" & l2

        Next l2

    Next l1

Next l3

End Sub
```

Output:

```
1-8
1-9
2-8
2-9
1-8
1-9
2-8
2-9
10-18
10-19
11-18
11-19
10-18
10-19
11-18
11-19
```

This code it's easier to understand but you can make it shorter with an aditional loop and benefit from IIf:

```
Sub Example()

Dim l1 As Integer
Dim l2 As Integer
Dim l3 As Integer
Dim l4 As Integer

For l4 = 0 To 9 Step 9
    For l3 = 1 To 2
        For l1 = 1 To 2
            For l2 = 8 To 9
                Debug.Print l1 + l4 & "-" & l2 + IIf(l4 = 0, 0, 1 + l4)
            Next l2
        Next l1
    Next l3
Next l4


End Sub
```